# Batik to SVG, setting scaling & canvas size

Tags: svg, graphics2d, vector-graphics, batik

We are using Batik so that we can create SVG documents using the java Graphics2D (actually a SVGGraphics2D). It all works great except for the scaling/sizing.

We want to use EMUs for the coordinates of all rendering. ([There are 914,400 EMUs/inch](https://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/points-inches-and-emus-measuring-units-in-office-open-xml/)).

The key code is:

```
// set the userspace to scale to EMUs. All calls pass EMUs for coordinates and this maps it to the pixels.
public static final int EPI = 914400;
int dpi = getDPI(); // returns 600
AffineTransform scaleToEmus = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(dpi / (float) EPI, dpi / (float) EPI);
graphics.transform(scaleToEmus);

// size (extent) of the SVG object.
svgGraphics.setSVGCanvasSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

This leads to a couple of problems. This eventually, this sets the width and height attributes on the `<svg>` element.

```
<svg width="1466850" height="1200150" …
```

The constructor also applies the affine transform which scales EMUs to pixels. And the SVG XML will contain something like

```
<g transform="matrix(0.0007,0,0,0.0007,0,0)" …
```

The problem is that the transform is not applied to `<svg>`’s width and height.  And it can be solved by applying the scale explicitly in the constructor

```
svgGraphics.setSVGCanvasSize(new Dimension((int)Math.ceil(width * graphics.getTransform().getScaleX()), (int)Math.ceil(height * graphics.getTransform().getScaleY())));
```

However, this doesn’t work well in all cases.  For example if DPI=600, width=1466850 (emu), then scaleX becomes 6.561679765582085E-4 and the scaled width becomes 963.  But the svg will contain matrix(0.0007, …), which leads to a shape not fitting into the canvas.  That is a guy who produces the matrix element rounds the value so that 6.561679765582085E-4 => 0.0007.

A solution could be to find out the rounding algorithm and use it to scale the canvas size. But I am not a fan of tweaking numbers to see what passes my specific use cases.

What is the suggested approach to this problem?

Update: Is the answer maybe to do the scaling via defining the viewBox?